# Why function on ng-checked is not getting called

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have called a function on ng-checked and through that function it is getting decided whether checkbox will be checked or not. But the function is not getting called at the load of page.

html -

```
<label>
     <input type="checkbox" name="status1" id="status1" ng-click="vm.updateStatus('processing')" ng-checked="vm.isSelectedStatus('processing')"> In progress
</label>
```

JS(controller) -

```
var vm = this;
vm.isSelectedStatus = isSelectedStatus;

vm.tasksStatus = ["processing", "finished", "failed"];

function isSelectedStatus(status) {
  return vm.tasksStatus.indexOf(status) > -1;
}

function updateStatus(status) {
        var index;

        index = vm.tasksStatus.indexOf(status);

        if(index === -1) {
            vm.tasksStatus.push(status);
        } else {
            vm.tasksStatus.splice(index, 1)   
        }
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean by load of a page?

Comment: @Sajeetharan when I am refreshing the page.

Comment: how do you excpect ng-checked to fire on page refresh?

Comment: Have you used controllerAs syntax when you are using this instead of $scope ??

Comment: What behavior do you want at page load?  Based on the code above, I believe that all three checkboxes would be marked.  Is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

The code is working properly as I can see..

You almost posted your full code, why not make some minimal extra effort to make it a runnable snippet? Then you can know this part of the code has no issue.

```js
angular.module('test', []).controller('Test', Test);

function Test() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.isSelectedStatus = isSelectedStatus;
  vm.updateStatus = updateStatus;

  vm.tasksStatus = ["processing", "finished", "failed"];

  function isSelectedStatus(status) {
    return vm.tasksStatus.indexOf(status) > -1;
  }

  function updateStatus(status) {
    var index;

    index = vm.tasksStatus.indexOf(status);

    if (index === -1) {
      vm.tasksStatus.push(status);
    } else {
      vm.tasksStatus.splice(index, 1)
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='test' ng-controller='Test as vm'>
  <label>
     <input type="checkbox" name="status1" id="status1" ng-click="vm.updateStatus('processing')" ng-checked="vm.isSelectedStatus('processing')"> In progress
  </label>
  
  <div>{{vm.tasksStatus}}</div>
</div>
```